# 18f26k20 with 20mhz oscillator and PLL enabled

Tags: microcontroller, pic

am i right that the pic 18f26k20 cannot be driven with an external 20mhz oscillator and the PLL enabled?
i have tried it - it worked. but will it be reliable?
i am not sure that i fully understood the datasheet.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Of course isn't reliable! Max CPU speed depend also of outside temperature and power supply voltage.
So if your power supply voltage is 3.6V and temperature is below 50°C than propably can work.

Check the datasheet...

[image]